# How do I memoize expensive calculations on Django model objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models, memoization

I have several TextField columns on my UserProfile object which contain JSON objects. I've also defined a setter/getter property for each column which encapsulates the logic for serializing and deserializing the JSON into python datastructures.

The nature of this data ensures that it will be accessed many times by view and template logic within a single Request. To save on deserialization costs, I would like to memoize the python datastructures on read, invalidating on direct write to the property or save signal from the model object.

Where/How do I store the memo? I'm nervous about using instance variables, as I don't understand the magic behind how any particular UserProfile is instantiated by a query. Is `__init__` safe to use, or do I need to check the existence of the memo attribute via `hasattr()` at each read?

Here's an example of my current implementation:

```
class UserProfile(Model):
    text_json = models.TextField(default=text_defaults)

    @property
    def text(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "text_memo"):
            self.text_memo = None
        self.text_memo = self.text_memo or simplejson.loads(self.text_json)
        return self.text_memo
    @text.setter
    def text(self, value=None):
        self.text_memo = None
        self.text_json = simplejson.dumps(value)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may be interested in a built-in django decorator `django.utils.functional.memoize`.

Django uses this to cache expensive operation like url resolving.

Comment: For class methods, I prefer using `django.utils.functional.cached_property`. Since the first argument on a class method is `self`, memoize will maintain a reference to the object and the results of the function even after you've thrown it away. This can cause memory leaks by preventing the garbage collector from cleaning up the stale object. `cached_property` turns Daniel's suggestion into a decorator.

Comment: Arion, this is exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: If anyone is interested, [cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) is a documented since Django 1.5

Comment: @Arion could you give a sample of how you mix class methods and cached_property?

Comment: Deprecated since 1.9.

Comment: @iTayb - you probably should have elaborated...  [`memoize` is deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.7/#django-utils-functional-memoize-function) in favour of `django.utils.lru_cache.lru_cache` or `functools.lru_cache`.  However, `cached_property` is still fine to use in 1.9 and isn't deprecated.

Comment: @Arion, can you please add your comment as an answer? It should really be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 18):

Generally, I use a pattern like this:

```
def get_expensive_operation(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_expensive_operation'):
        self._expensive_operation = self.expensive_operation()
    return self._expensive_operation
```

Then you use the `get_expensive_operation` method to access the data.

However, in your particular case, I think you are approaching this in slightly the wrong way. You need to do the deserialization when the model is first loaded from the database, and serialize on save only. Then you can simply access the attributes as a standard Python dictionary each time. You can do this by defining a custom JSONField type, subclassing models.TextField, which overrides `to_python` and `get_db_prep_save`.

In fact someone's already done it: see [here](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1478/).

Comment: You're entirely right. We were already getting annoyed that we had to receive the dictionary, manipulate it, and then send it back to the setter. Manipulating the dictionary in place is much nicer.

The JSON field implementation is interesting, but I'm uncertain how it works behind the scenes. Does it deserialize once on load, providing a manipulable python object, which it then serializes again on save?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In between, it's a normal dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

For class methods, you should use `django.utils.functional.cached_property`.

Since the first argument on a class method is `self`, `memoize` will maintain a reference to the object and the results of the function even after you've thrown it away. This can cause memory leaks by preventing the garbage collector from cleaning up the stale object. `cached_property` turns Daniel's suggestion into a decorator.