# django: how to memoize model manager methods?

Tags: python, django, memoization, django-managers

I have a memoized Django model manager method as follows:

```
class GroupManager(models.Manager):
    def get_for_user(self, user):
        cache_key = 'groups_%s' % (user.id)
        if not hasattr(self, key):
            groups = get_groups_somehow()
            setattr(self, cache_key, groups)
        return getattr(self, cache_key)
```

But the memoized value persists beyond the request / response cycle; i.e. the value is not re-calculated in the subsequent requests until the server is restarted. This must be because the manager instance is not destroyed.

So, how can I properly memoize model manager methods?

Comment: Are you talking about caching and cache invalidation?

Comment: i am talking about doing this in a manager method: http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2009/12/20/django-patterns-memoizing/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I memoize expensive calculations on Django model objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526191/how-do-i-memoize-expensive-calculations-on-django-model-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1526245/287923, but simplifying it, i've implemented a request cache as follows:

```
from threading import currentThread

caches = {}

class RequestCache(object):
    def set(self, key, value):
        cache_id = hash(currentThread())
        if caches.get(cache_id):
            caches[cache_id][key] = value
        else:
            caches[cache_id] = {key: value}

    def get(self, key):
        cache_id = hash(currentThread())
        cache = caches.get(cache_id)
        if cache:
            return cache.get(key)
        return None

class RequestCacheMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        cache_id = hash(currentThread())
        if caches.get(cache_id):
            del(caches[cache_id])
        return response
```

`caches` is a dictionary of cache dictionaries, accessed via `get` & `set` methods. a middleware clears the cache for the current thread in `process_response` method, after the response is rendered.

it is used like this:

```
from request_cache import RequestCache
cache = RequestCache()
cache.get(key)
cache.set(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key value is not recalculated because you tell it to not be recalculated once the key exists. If you want to recalculate it in subsequent calls, reorder your code

```
class GroupManager(models.Manager):
    def get_for_user(self, user):
        cache_key = 'groups_%s' % (user.id)
        groups = get_groups_somehow()
        setattr(self, cache_key, groups)
        return getattr(self, cache_key)
```

And if you want to get the value cached without recalculating, just use `getattr` with the correct key on your manager.

Comment: thanks, but purpose of this is to avoid recalculation when the same method is called multiple times within one request / response cycle. but manager methods seem to persist in django. for memoizing pattern see: http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2009/12/20/django-patterns-memoizing/